# Query random but unread keys the Redis way

Tags: redis

I have thousands of messages each stored like a list of properties (text, subject, date, etc) in a separate key: `msg:1001`, `msg:1002` etc...

There is also a list keyed as `messages` with ids of all existing messages: `1001,1002,1003...`

Now I need to get 10 random messages.

But, I only need those messages that are not *flagged* by the user (sort of unread).

There is a hash for each user keyed as `flags:USERID` = `1001=red,1005=blue,1010=red,...`

Currently I have to keep in memory of my application a full list of messages plus all flags for all users currently logged in and do all the math by hand (in JavaScript).

Is there a way to do such a query in Redis way, with no duplicating all the data on the application end?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is an example of a [space–time tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff). On the one hand, you say that you don't want to keep a list of the unflagged messages in your system, but I would guess that you also want to keep your application relatively fast. Therefore, I suggest giving up some space and keeping a set of unflagged messages.

As messages are created in your system, add them both to `messages` ([`SADD messages <messageid>`](http://redis.io/commands/sadd)) and `messages_unflagged` ([`SADD messages_unflagged <messageid>`](http://redis.io/commands/sadd)). After a user adds a flag to a message, remove the message from the unflagged set ([`SREM messages_unflagged <messageid>`](http://redis.io/commands/srem)). When you need 10 random, unflagged messages, you can get their IDs in constant time ([`SRANDMEMBER messages_unflagged 10`](http://redis.io/commands/srandmember)).